# how can add 10 marks when collision is detected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

```py
score_value = 0
lives_value = 3

# Check if collide/overlap
def collision(rleft, rtop, rlength, cX, cY, radius):
    rright = rleft + rlength
    cbottom = cY + radius
    score_value = 0
    lives_value = 3
    if (rleft <= cX <= rright) and (cbottom >= rtop):
        score_value += 10
    else:
        lives_value -= 1
```

```py
# Defining variables
rright = rect_x + rect_length
rbottom = rect_y + rect_width

# Call the collision() function
collision(rect_x, rect_y , rect_length, circle_x, circle_y, radius)
```

I have to create a pygame which when a circle collides with a rectangle, 10 points should be added. But now the score just kept increasing like crazy, even when the ball is falling, how can I fix this? Above are the codes i wrote for this project. [original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcXi6.png)PLEASE HELP

Comment: This is probably happening due to collisions being detected way too many times on different vertices. You should try disabling/destroying one of the objects so that too many collisions aren't detected. I'm not writing this as an answer as I don't know much about pygame. Hope this helps!

Comment: Once you detect a colissoin dont allow another collision to trigger until they uncollide. Whats probably happening is you're checking for collision on every game loop, which is probably around 60 times a second, so as long as the two object collide you're getting 600 points a second

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the collision is not detected just once. It is recognized several times in consecutive frames. Add a return value to the function `collision` that indicates if the collision was detected:

```py
def collision(rleft, rtop, rlength, cX, cY, radius):
    rright = rleft + rlength
    cbottom = cY + radius
    score_value = 0
    lives_value = 3
    collision = (rleft <= cX <= rright) and (cbottom >= rtop)

    if collision:
        score_value += 10
    else:
        lives_value -= 1
    return collision:
```

Add a variable `rect_circle_collided` to the application and store the result of `collision` to the variable. Only Invoke  `collision` if `rect_circle_collided` is `False`:

```py
rect_circle_collided = False

while not done:

    # [...]

    # Call the collision() function
    if not rect_circle_collided:
        rect_circle_collided = collision(rect_x, rect_y , rect_length, circle_x, circle_y, radius)
```

Note you have to reset the state (`rect_circle_collided = False`) when you create new circle at the top of the window.